# Regex parse multi lines string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse

```
Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

using javascript regex.

My goal is to obtain something like this:

```
{
    Mode: 'Managed',
    Frequency: '2.462 Ghz',
    Access Point: ''
}
```

I tried something like this :

```
((Mode\s*):\s*)(\w+)
```

but I obtain 3 results: `Mode: Managed`, `Mode:` and `Mode`.
Any idea ?

Comment: Post your code. Which function did you used ?

Comment: Post an example of the text you want to parse (2 or 3 lines at least) along with the expected output.

Comment: You have only one line in the example

Comment: Exact duplicate of [What is the purpose of the passive (non-capturing) group in a Javascript regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578714/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-passive-non-capturing-group-in-a-javascript-regex)

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson The duplicate link is useless. And this can be done using RegExp :3.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "\
Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:00:00:00:00:00\n\
Mode:UnManaged  Frequency:3.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:00:00:00:00:00\n\
Mode:UnUnManaged  Frequency:4.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:00:00:00:00:00\
";

// look for some characters between "Mode:" and "Frequency:" group them as the first group
// look for some characters between "Frequency:" and "Access Point:" group them as the second group
// look for some characters after "Access Point:" group them as the third group
var regex = /Mode:\s*(.+)\s+Frequency:\s*(.+)\s+Access Point:\s*(.+)/gm;

var r, res = [];
while(r = regex.exec(str)) {
    res.push({
        "Mode": r[1].trim(),            // the first group is the Mode (trim to remove an leading or trailing spaces) 
        "Frequency": r[2].trim(),       // ...
        "Access Point": r[3].trim()     // ...
    });
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following regex.

**Regex:** `(Mode:\S*)\s*(Frequency:\S*\s*GHz)\s*(Access Point:\s*\S*)`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tV56fk/1)**

Answer (score 0):

> but I obtain 3 results: `Mode: Managed`, `Mode:` and `Mode`.
>   Any idea ?

You have 3 capturing groups so you capture three things.

Answer (score 0):

#### Text

```
"Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:00:00:00:00:00  "
```

#### Regex:

```
(.*:.*)\ {2}
```

#### Result:

1. Mode:Managed
2. Frequency:2.462 GHz
3. Access Point: 00:00:00:00:00:00